# Why is formally unramified preserved under base change?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Le $f:X\to S$ be a formally unramified morphism of schemes and $T\to S$ another morphism of schemes. I'd like to prove that the base change $X_T\to T$ stays formally unramified. So let $Y$ be a $T$-scheme with $Y_0$ a first order thickening,  $f,g:Y\to X_T$ with $f\circ i=g\circ i$ so we have $\alpha\circ f\circ i=\alpha\circ g\circ i$ so using the formal unramification of $X$ one gets that $\alpha\circ f=\alpha\circ g$ and the following diagram:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
X @<\alpha<< X_T     @<<<  Y_0\\
@VV\lambda V   @VV\beta V @VViV\\
S     @<\gamma <<  T @<\mu<< Y
\end{CD}

Question: how can I conclude that $f=g$? The morphism $\alpha$ is not a monomorphism?

My definition of formally unramified: for every affine $S$-scheme $Y$ and for every closed subscheme $Y_0\subseteq Y$ given by a quasi-coherent ideal $\mathcal{I}\subseteq\mathcal{O}_Y$ of square $\mathcal{I}^2=0$, the canonical map $\text{Hom}_S(Y,X)\to\text{Hom}_S(Y_0,X)$ is injective.

Answer (score 1):

The key idea here is the universal property of the fiber product: a morphism $Y\to X_T$ is uniquely equivalent to two morphisms $Y\to X$ and $Y\to T$ which agree when composed with the morphisms $X\to S$ and $T\to S$. If we have a morphism $Y\to X_T$ making the diagram commute, it must be the morphism induced by the universal property of the fiber product by the morphisms $Y\to T$ and $Y\to X$. As the morphism $Y\to T$ is specified and there is at most one morphism $Y\to X$ making the diagram commute (as $X\to S$ is formally unramified), we see that if there is a morphism $Y\to X_T$ making the diagram commute, it is unique.

Comment: Ok thanks: all is clear! The question is: why I never see such trivialities...